# Sliced image positioning

Tags: css, html, iframe, positioning

I've been scouring the forums without a clear solution to my problem so I figured I'd give stackoverflow a go.  In short, I need to know how I should go about positioning the elements on my site.  When maximized, the images appear fine with the iframe as it should be.  Upon resizing the browser, my sliced images shift to the left and distort my layout.  My question is, should I use and div within a div to position my elements or is there another method I should be searching for?  I know that I could possibly use CSS to position things but I would like a clear answer if possible as I've already spent countless hours on this.  Thank you and my apologies in advance if I've left out pertinent information.

http://hrsolavei.dx.am is where the site is located, please take a look and give me some feed back.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to position the content of your website using an iframe like you have it right now, and the layout in a separate table, then you need to give your iframe the css of position:absolute; right:50%; Then, for the div surrounding your iframe, the css should be overflow:visible; position:absolute; left:50%;

Now, I implore you to please research web development best practices, as they will make your website much easier to develop, and easier to change later on. The big ones that I noticed are that you should try using divs for your layout instead of tables. Tables are meant for storing information much like the image in your iframe does. You should also look into organizing all of your styles using a css file.